# How would you use a switch statement with a combination of 3 binary inputs? (C)

Tags: c, switch-statement, sensors, pic, mplab

I'm coding a PIC18F252 microcontroller in C. The program should take 3 separate inputs from sensors (run through the ADC first), and then depending on the combination of these 3 inputs it will select an output from the switch statement. 
So for example, if each sensor outputs a 0, I would want to select the case '000' and execute its instructions. If the middle sensor outputs a 1, I want case 010 etc.

I've looked into doing this using arrays or strings to store the 3 character value, but I don't seem to be able to use the switch statement correctly to compare the input to the case.

It seems that an if/else statement would be a more simplistic way of doing this but I need to use switch.

So can anyone tell me if its possible to compare an array or string with the cases, or if there's any other way to do this? Only other way I can think of would be to assign the input combo to a word variable, but this would require a switch or if/else statement of its own.

Comment: `switch(sensorValue) { case 0: ... break; case 1: ... break; }`. What part about this is causing a problem?

Comment: Can you bit shift the first 2 inputs and combine the 3 of them with ORs ?

Comment: @Frontear I think the problem is that OP wants to combine the 3 inputs into one switchable value: `switch(combine(input1, input2, input3)) {...}`

Comment: "It seems that an if/else statement would be a more simplistic way of doing this"
Agreed.
"but I need to use switch."
Why?

Comment: You write about ADC and show sensor values 0 and 1 only. Do you mean digital inputs instead of ADC? Or is this 0/1 value a result of some processing of the ADC values?

Comment: @EddInglis its coursework so has to be done to a specification

Comment: @Bodo the sensors output an analogue value, the PIC uses a built in analogue to digital converter (ADC) to convert the values to digital. Then the digital values can be used in the switch statement

Comment: @Sam Please [edit] your question and add all clarification or requested information there. Of course an ADC will give you a digital value, but normally it will be any value in a certain range, e.g. 0 .. 0x3FF, i.e. a numeric value. A combination of numeric values is not well suited for a `switch` ... `case` statement. If your values are in fact boolean values or bits (0 or 1), you can use the proposed solution. Please state the range of your three input values **in your question**.

Answer (score 2):

If the input values are digital values (0 or 1), you can combine the bits to a single number by bit shifting and bit-wise OR.

Example:

```
int input1 = 0;
int input2 = 1;
int input3 = 1;
int combined;

/* assuming the values can be 0 or 1 only */
combined = input1 | ( input2 << 1 ) | ( input3 << 2 );
/* or with any non-zero value as TRUE */
combined = (input1 ? 1 << 0 : 0) | (input2 ? 1 << 1 : 0) | ( input3 ? 1 << 2 : 0);

switch(combined)
{
case 0x0: // or GCC extension 0xb000
case 0x1: // or GCC extension 0xb001
case 0x2: // or GCC extension 0xb010
case 0x3: // or GCC extension 0xb011
/* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look through this later to make sure I understand your example, but it looks like it should be exactly what I need.